# Redirect permanently from fake directory to a real one without the drive path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect permanently from one fake directory to a real one.
This `.htaccess` file is located in my root (www) folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^fake/(.*)$ /real/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^fake$ /real [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
```

When I type in the address bar `http://localhost/fake` or even `http://localhost/fake/index.php?id=1`, I hope to get this url: `http://localhost/real` or `http://localhost/real/index.php?id=1`.

But instead, I get the following url with a 403 Forbbiden, because I disabled indexes:

> `http://localhost/C:/wamp64/www/real`
>
> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /C:/wamp64/www/real/ on this server.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does `http://localhost/fake/index.php?id=1` also give 403?

Comment: @anubhava no, but it gives 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your code like this in site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Multiviews
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^fake(?:/(.*))?$ /real/$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to test using a new browser.

Comment: It's almost great but I can't access it when I use only `fake/` or without the slash (It works only with a file after it, `fake/index.php`)

Comment: Test it with just this code in .htaccess. `?` at the end of `(?:/(.*))?` makes trailing slash optional

Comment: Like this: `^fake(?:/(.*)?)?$`?

Comment: Great. the problem was with Firefox, probably cache or something. Listen, I worship you. Thank you very much!